# Turning on "E_ALL" (errors) in php.ini

Tags: macos, php, mamp, php.ini

I've turned on errors in `php.ini` by removing the `;` in front of the comment on line 240 of `php.ini` (I'm using PHP 5.4.4).

I'm using MAMP for my local server to set up a local environment, and I changed the `php.ini` settings in *Applications > MAMP > bin > php5.4.4 > conf > php.ini*      (this is on OS X 10.8).

I'm still getting blank screen errors when my PHP is wrong, which is quite often, as I've just started with it. Is this the right place / way to set the errors?

Comment: Please include the actual line you uncommented. The line numbers will be different for different people.

Comment: @terdon the line is "E_ALL             - All errors and warnings"

Comment: OK, I see what is wrong. Have a look at my answer. You uncommented the wrong line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you have edited is a comment, not a directive. The PHP.ini file has a lot of information to help you out, most of it is only for *you* to read and not the computer.

You need to make sure that the following lines are not commented (have no `;` at the beginning of the line) and have the correct values:

```
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

They will not necessarily be present and commented. On my system, for example, the `display_errors` line looked like this:

```
display_errors = Off
```

What you uncommented was a line explaining some of the PHP.ini options. It is there to explain to human users how to configure the file. Normal options have the format (note the `=`):

```
option_name = option_value
```

As you can  see, the line you edited does not have that format. The equivalent line on my system looks like this:

```
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (includes E_STRICT as of PHP 5.4.0)
```

Uncommenting that line will not help. In fact, I am surprised that PHP would work at all with it uncommented.

Comment: cheers @terdon !

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at this?

[Enable PHP Error Reporting in MAMP | Gilbert Pellegrom](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/enable-php-error-reporting-in-mamp/)

> - Open up `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/{your PHP version}/conf/php.ini`.
> - Find `display_errors = Off` (around line 277) and change it to `display_errors = On`.
> - Restart MAMP.

Comment: Justin, please 1) don't address the OP by their name, 2) [include the relevant parts of a link here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259), on-site, 3) [don't post LMGTFY links](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5642/) and 4) don't sign your posts. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies sir @slhck

Answer (score 1):

The E_ALL in the php.ini is a default level for error reporting.
This can be overridden by the function named "error_reporting" in a .php file. And if that file is run, or it's included from a running script, it will override the default level. You can search for the function "error_reporting" in those files and check that the level is not lower than E_ALL.